# What is the Difference between SparkSession.conf and SparkConf?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I understand that you create a SparkSession from a SparkConf object but does that mean the SparkSession.conf is the same as SparkConf()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**, **if** (`SparkSession.builder.config(conf=SparkConf())`) you create your SparkSessioin with SparkConf object

You can  confirm this from PySpark source code

here is the code for [SparkSession.conf](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/session.py/#L269) , which returns `self._conf` and if you back track this you can see that it's getting set or created in `getOrCreate` method [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/session.py/#143)

In `getOrCreate` method you can observe that SparkConf set with options that are passed at the creation time of SparkSession

[image]

You can further check that `self._options` set with values in `config` method [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.4/python/pyspark/sql/session.py/#L88) which in our case passing SparkConf object's (key, value)

[image]